# Запретить отправку сообщений сокету

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, tcp

В цикле идет обработка входящих сообщений и при необходимости отправка ответа.
Но возникают ситуации, когда отправлять ответ не нужно. Возможно ли запретить сокету (например, из другого потока) отправлять сообщения без его закрытия, а потом так же разрешить? Не хотелось бы переписывать кучу методов ради этого, поэтому ищу возможность сделать это проще.

Comment: У вас же есть метод, где отправляете сообщения в сокет? Почему там не написать `if (условие) {отправка сообщения} else выход`?

Comment: Этих методов много и они универсальные.

Comment: Ваша программа не может договориться сама с собой? Ну так не делайте много методов для одного и того же, сделайте центральный метод. Ваша проблема решается нормальной архитектурой, а не тем, что правая нога делает подножку левой.

Comment: Я с вами согласен, но на данном этапе в связи с возникшими обстоятельствами мне было бы удобно сделать именно так. Да и из любопытства захотелось разобраться.

Comment: Добавляя технический долг со словами `на данном этапе в связи с возникшими обстоятельствами мне было бы удобно сделать именно так` - вы только себе хуже делаете. Все долги с этими словами и добавляются.